# Cucumber is not able to separate two different string from data table

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

**Description**: Login Window contains 3 main objects "username"(textbox) , "password"(textbox) and "login"(button)

**Observation**: when running test, in username text box it is entering testtest(i.e. entering value of password in the same editbox)

Could you please help me with this issue as it is breaking basic functionality and it is a blocker for me to automate?

**Feature file:**

```
    @login
Feature: Login
    Scenario Outline: Login
    Given I launch url 
    Then I enter <username>
    Then I enter password <password>
    Then I click on login button
    Then I verify login screen
    Then I click on logOut
    Examples: 
     | username | password   |
     | test           | test        |
```

**StepDefinition**

```
    Given(/^I launch webapp url$/, function () {
    return browser.get('https://example.com');
    });
Then(/^I enter (.*)$/, function (username) {
        const Login = new loginPage();
        return Login.enterUserName(username);
    });
Then(/^I enter password (password)$/, function (password) {
        const Login = new loginPage();
        return Login.enterPassword(password);
        console.log('pass');
    });
```

Comment: What is the `LoginPage();` function you are referring to?

Comment: Please give HTML code of login window,  code of  `enterUserName` and `enterPassword`,  the locator of username and password.

Answer (score 0):

The issue obviously comes from your code. First, please check you not use same element variable in function `enterUserName()` and  `enterPassword`.

Second, check the locator for finding username and password won't find same element on page.

Third,  A issue in your code: `Then(/^I enter password (password)$/, function (password) {`

It should be `Then(/^I enter password (.*)$/, function (password) {`

Comment: hey thanks for highlighting my silly mistake :(
your Third point did changed my issue from non working to working state